# Mutual information and computing one variable using the other

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Is there any theory that connects between the mutual information of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ and the ability to approximate $f(X) \approx Y$ using a best fitting function $f$? Differently said, is there a measurement that connects $I(X;Y)$ and a quantity of the form $\displaystyle\inf_{f \in \mathcal{C}}\, \mathbb{E}_{(X,Y)}[\|f(X)-Y\|^2]?$

Comment: Perhaps relevant https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171916/relationship-between-least-squares-regression-and-information-theory https://www.princeton.edu/~verdu/reprints/GuoShaVer.Apr2005.pdf

Comment: I'm not sure it's relevant. Since in both cases, there is an assumption on the structure of Y given X. Therefore, there is no need to take inf_f.

Comment: There is a straightforward connection if we use zero-one loss function - basically Fano's inequality. I doubt that anything can be said in general for least mean squared error, because the entropy (and mutual information) does not depend on the "size" of the discrepancy.